# convert pdf to image with itext in android

Tags: android, itext

i search to convert pdf file to image in android , itry with itextpdf-5.3.1.jar

but i have exception in my appliction. i aded the library in libs folder .

ther is my code

```
    package com.example.zakiexemple;


import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;


import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    PdfReader reader;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);

        //final WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);



       bt.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {



@Override

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            File file = new File("/sdcard/003_overview.pdf");
            try{
                reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
                    PdfObject pdfobj= reader.getPdfObject(i);
                    if (pdfobj == null || !pdfobj.isStream()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) pdfobj;
                    PdfObject pdfsubtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);

                    if (pdfsubtype != null && pdfsubtype.toString().equals(PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {
                        byte[] img = PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw((PRStream) stream);
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new 
                        File(file.getParentFile(),String.format("%1$05d", i) + ".jpg"));
                        out.write(img); out.flush(); out.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "howa hadak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }


        }
    })   ; 
    } 

    }
```

and for log error

`03-15 08:12:35.835: E/dalvikvm(937): Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj
03-15 08:12:35.835: W/dalvikvm(937): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1533 (Lorg/bouncycastle/cert/X509CertificateHolder;) in Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader;
03-15 08:12:35.835: D/dalvikvm(937): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x030e
03-15 08:12:35.946: D/dalvikvm(937): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x318a at 0x318 in Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader;.readDecryptedDocObj
03-15 08:12:35.946: D/dalvikvm(937): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x31a5 at 0x33d in Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader;.readDecryptedDocObj
03-15 08:12:36.505: D/dalvikvm(937): GC_CONCURRENT freed 743K, 14% free 5345K/6212K, paused 71ms+85ms, total 216ms`

i think i havent the good itext library for android.

can you give the good link .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText 5 cannot be directly used on Android in most cases. There are several technical incompatibilities which forced us to make a port with changes specifically made to support Android. One of these changes is the use of SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle.

This version can be found on Maven central or the [iText Repository](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/releases/com/itextpdf/itextg).
To make use of this, you will need a license. Or you can try out the software with a trial license which can be requested on the iText website.

Comment: hy michel thank you. where can i add the key file in my progect

Comment: i have another log exception:
amil application not found.
my question is in my programme i don't use any of email application.

why this error

Comment: The key file can be added by using the LoadLicenseFile method of LicenseFile. Could be a similar name, going from the top of my head. As for your "amil" log, could you post a bit more information?

Comment: but where can i find licenseFile in my project , there is no file with the same name

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: @EASStandswithUkraine link has been updated. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey can we still use iText 5 for free commercially?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer: 
The answer is more complex than a simple yes or no and mostly depends on whether or not you make your sources available.

Comment: For more information you could read the AGPL or this page on our website: https://itextpdf.com/en/how-buy/agpl-license